# jvm exception catching

Tags: java, debugging, exception, jvm

So I recently wrote a java class that extends exception and used an instance of this class to check cases and throw itself if an error occurs. I found out that when the caller of main catches this exception, the line it says the exception was thrown from is the line from where the exception was created, and not from where it was thrown. I'm just wondering why this is, and whether it is intended behavior for the jvm or not since this is not a common way of throwing exceptions. If it is intended behavior, what is the rational for this as it seems like the line number from where the exception was thrown would be more useful(and probably easier to track through the stack). Sample cases follow demonstrating expected behavior and unexpected.

---

Normal Exception throwing:

```
1  public class Test
2  {
3   public static void main(String ... args) throws Throwable
4   {
5       switch(5)
6       {
7           case 1: throw new Exception("Exception");
8           case 2: throw new Exception("Exception");
9           case 3: throw new Exception("Exception");
10          case 4: throw new Exception("Exception");
11          case 5: throw new Exception("Exception");
12      }
13  }
14 }
```

output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: Exception
    at Test.main(Test.java:11)
```

---

My Approach(simplified):

```
1  public class Test
2  {
3   public static void main(String ... args) throws Throwable
4   {
5       Exception e = new Exception("Exception");
6       switch(5)
7       {
8           case 1: throw e;
9           case 2: throw e;
10          case 3: throw e;
11          case 4: throw e;
12          case 5: throw e;
13      }
14  }
15 }
```

output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: Exception
    at Test.main(Test.java:5)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> the line it says the exception was thrown from is the line from where
>   the exception was created, and not from where it was thrown. I'm just
>   wondering why this is, and whether it is intended behavior for the jvm
>   or not

Yes. It is not only intended but documented. See the Javadoc for `java.lang.Throwable`: 'A throwable contains a snapshot of the execution stack of its thread at the time it was created.' If you don't want that, you have the option of calling `fillInStackTrace()` just before throwing it.

Answer (score 0):

From the [JavaDoc for Throwable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getStackTrace%28%29):

> Typically, this is the point at which this throwable was created and
>   thrown.

Which is a little ambiguous, but 99% of the time an exception is created at the point it is thrown.  I guess creating the stack trace from the point of creation makes more sense when you consider re-throwing exceptions, for example:

```
void bar() throws Exception
{
    throw Exception();
}

void foo() throws Exception
{
    try
    {
        bar();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
   foo();
}
```

It's more useful knowing the exception was created in `bar()`, than knowing it was re-thrown in `foo()`.  If this information was important you could throw a new exception with the original as the cause argument.

**UPDATE**

To illustrate, if you really wanted to know that the exception was thrown in `foo()` as well then you would do this in `foo()`

```
void foo() throws Exception
{
    try
    {
        bar();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new Exception("Some more useful information from foo", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: but in your example you are throwing the exception at the same time you create it. In this case, if the exception was created elsewhere, you would still want to know that it was thrown from bar, and not where it was created. I guess as EJP said you have the option of this behavior by calling fill in stack trace so that more explains why they would design the throws clause this way.

Comment: I've updated the answer.  I'm not sure `fillInStrackTrace()` would have the behaviour you're talking about.  With exception handling you *really* want it to be as obvious as possible.  Especially for other people looking at your code.  I.e. prefer to create and throw exceptions at the same point as that is what 99% of people looking at stack traces expect.

Comment: i just tested it, and fillInStackTrace() does work as I intended. And its worth noting that in your example the stack trace reveals that the exception starts in bar and passes through foo on the way to main even without the extra code in foo. The issue isnt with what the standard convention is, i know my method seems a bit odd, but trust me in the context, it makes sense.